# Why would 10.5.7 not be listed in software update?

Tags: macos

I am running 10.5.6 and when I run Software Update it says that my system us up to date. Why would it not list 10.5.7? Has anyone else experienced this?

There was a suggestion on the Apple discussion boards to delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.softwareupdate.plist and reboot but it did not solve the issue.

I know I could download the combo updated but surely there is some kind of problem if Software Update doesn't list it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could download it directly here: http://support.apple.com/downloads/Mac_OS_X_10_5_7_Update

It appears other people have had the same problem with previous released versions: http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/12/mac-os-x-1056-update-doesnt-li.html

It just seems that software update breaks sometimes rather than a error with your mac personally, it's a OSX bug.